# Strange problem with a C# function I am trying to write

Tags: c#

I have this function I am writing.

```
  const int ProgressBarLength = 230;
  foreach (TransactionDetail item in list)
  {
      var itemProgress =
        ((ProgressBarLength/item.PurchasesRequired) *
        Convert.ToInt32(item.TransactionAmount));

      item.ProgressBar = itemProgress > ProgressBarLength ? ProgressBarLength : itemProgress;
  }
```

Now I have 2 `TransactionDetail`s in my loop.

If `item.PurchasesRequired = 500` and `TransactionAmount = 199.0` the resulting value is 0. However, if `item.PurchasesRequired = 5` and `TransactionAmount = 94.0` it returns a valid result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're performing integer division.

230 / 500 is zero in integer division, whereas 230 / 5 is 46.

You can force floating-point division by casting `PurchasesRequired` to a `double`. 230 / 500 is 0.46 in floating-point division, as you'd expect.

```
const int ProgressBarLength = 230;
foreach (TransactionDetail item in list)
{
    var itemProgress = ((ProgressBarLength / (double)item.PurchasesRequired)
                        * Convert.ToInt32(item.TransactionAmount));
    item.ProgressBar = Math.Min((int)itemProgress, ProgressBarLength);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Is `item.PurchasesRequired` an `int`?

If so, your problem is integer division.

`ProgressBarLength` is an `int`, so 230/500 = 0.

Use `float`, `double`, or `decimal` (either in a cast or for your ProgressBarLength) to maintain your desired level of precision.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you should do a cast to double somewhere to have more precision in your divisions. When dividing an int by an int, you won't get a double as result.

Try the following:

```
double itemProgress = ( ((double)ProgressBarLength / item.PurchasesRequired )
                      * Convert.ToInt32( item.TransactionAmount ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing TransactionDetail.PurchaseRequired is a field or property of type int.

ProgressBarLength/item.PurchasesRequired divides an in by an int which results in an int, not a float. in your first example, 230 / 500 does integer division and the result is, of course, 0.

You can either calculate the expression as a double, or do the multiplication first so that you don't lose relevant precision from the integer division.

```
var itemProgress = (double) ProgressBarLength / item.PurchasesRequired * item.TransactionAmount;
```

or

```
var itemProgress = ProgressBarLength * (int) item.TransactionAmount / item.PurchasesRequired));
```